# Weekly Weight Based on a category using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data and looking to create the "Final Col" shown below using dplyr in R. I would appreciate your ideas.

```
| Year  | Week    | MainCat|Qty    |Final Col     |
|:----: |:------: |:-----: |:-----:|:------------:|
| 2017  | 1       | Edible |69     |69/(69+12)    |
| 2017  | 2       | Edible |12     |12/(69+12)    |
| 2017  | 1       | Flowers|88     |88/(88+47)    |
| 2017  | 2       | Flowers|47     |47/(88+47)    |
| 2018  | 1       | Edible |90     |90/(90+35)    |
| 2018  | 2       | Edible |35     |35/(90+35)    |
| 2018  | 1       | Flowers|78     |78/(78+85)    |
| 2018  | 2       | Flowers|85     |85/(78+85)    |
```

Comment: So weeks 1 and 2 are being grouped each time they repeat?

Comment: Yes. The original data goes up to week 53. 

So I would like to sum all the weeks for the edible category for the year 2017, and then divide each week of 2018 by the total for 2018...

and repeat this process for every year and main category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a `group_by` operation i.e. grouped by 'Year', 'MainCat', divide the 'Qty' by the `sum` of 'Qty' to create the 'Final' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
       group_by(Year, MainCat) %>%
       mutate(Final = Qty/sum(Qty))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prop.table` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Year, MainCat) %>% mutate(Final = prop.table(Qty))

#   Year  Week MainCat   Qty Final
#  <int> <int> <chr>   <int> <dbl>
#1  2017     1 Edible     69 0.852
#2  2017     2 Edible     12 0.148
#3  2017     1 Flowers    88 0.652
#4  2017     2 Flowers    47 0.348
#5  2018     1 Edible     90 0.72 
#6  2018     2 Edible     35 0.28 
#7  2018     1 Flowers    78 0.479
#8  2018     2 Flowers    85 0.521
```

You can also do this in base R :

```
df$Final <- with(df, ave(Qty, Year, MainCat, FUN = prop.table))
```